# Connecting to tcp server from client running in android device

Tags: android, networking, network-programming

I am trying to connect to a standalone desktop tcp server(java) from tcp client application in android device.

But I am not able to connect to that.

I tried to write a desktop tcp client and tried to connect to server(remote server). It is working fine.

But When I am trying to connecting from android, I am getting a IOException while creating Socket instance.

Can anyone help me in this ? Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... for the time being we are doing this by checking the connection every `n` seconds.

```
Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
.....
}
}
```

But, still I want to know if there any way like getting callback upon socket connection lost...

Comment: You should make the callback yourself. socket.getInputStream().read() will return -1 when the socket is closed, so when your 'read thread' encounters this you can call your own callback. But yeah, I wish such a callback was build in too sometimes :).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, The problem is 
In Idle mode if I want to check socket status I cant do socket.getInputStream.read() to read from Server, because it may not send anything to in Idle mode. So,I am using socket.getOutputStream().write() to write and at the same time I can check the socket status. But still with this method, I am making unneccessary traffic on N/W and my app consume more CPU.
I have seen one API socket.isConnected(), but unfortunatly it is giving proper result when I closed the socket connection at server side.
Please let me know if U come across any solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question :)

Now, I am able to connect to server running in my PC from client running in Android device.

The problem is,

My server running in PC is connected to different IP N/W than the Wi-Fi N/W used by my Mobile. So even if I give the same IP address in client to connect to server, it can not connect, because IP address is relative(local) to the IP N/W.

So, if we are using relative IP for Server, we need to make sure that the both Server and client running devices should be connected over the same IP N/W.

It is a silly question and silly mistake and silly answer. :)

Comment: Hi All, I need to know one thing. I need to keep on check the Socket health(is it alive or not). 
For this I am keep on writing 1 byte of data to the server's outstream.
With this I am able to monitor the connection. But I kept this in infinite loop as I need to keep on check that forever. It is consuming more CPU cycles. Instead of that is there any way to check the connection status?

Thanks in advance..